# Oracle cumulative sum based on usage transactions

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, cumulative-sum

I need to cumulatively sum a value based on the condition that the value either matches or is only one record value higher than the column it should match to. I am making a system to track if the number of parts that were ordered have fully been used. Since you can order multiple quantity in a single order, and use small amounts of it at a time, I need to know when the ordered quantity has been used.

Example:

Subquery shows the usage transactions for each part

```
OrderNumber | PartNumber | OrderQty | LastUsageDate | Usage
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    10 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    11 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    11 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    12 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    13 - oct   |  2
```

And this is how my results look with the information above

```
OrderNumber | PartNumber | OrderQty | LastUsageDate | Usage
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    12 - oct   |  8
```

As you notice, the result stops the cumulative sum at 8 as it should and shows the LastUsageDate that it should. But, while it is running the cumulative sum, if it comes to a number that would make the sum greater than the OrderQty, it does not include it, that part is excluded from the results despite the fact that is has been fully used.

Here is an example of that.

```
OrderNumber | PartNumber | OrderQty | LastUsageDate | Usage
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    10 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    11 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    11 - oct   |  2
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    12 - oct   |  3
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    13 - oct   |  2
```

If this was the data for the part, it would not have any results because the cumulative sum goes from 6 to 9 from days 11-Oct to 12-Oct.

I need a way for the cumulative sum to include the record even though the sum would be greater than the OrderQty, but it then also needs to stop counting beyond that record. So my result should be.

```
OrderNumber | PartNumber | OrderQty | LastUsageDate | Usage
j55789      |  ks568     |  8       |    12 - oct   |  9
```

Here is the SQL:

```
    SELECT d1.* FROM(

    SELECT c1.*, max(c1.LastGiDate) LastGiDate, max(c1.cum_sum) GIQty  FROM(

    SELECT b1.*, SUM(b1.GiQty) OVER (PARTITION BY b1.MRNum, b1.PartNo ORDER BY b1.LastGiDate) cum_sum FROM(***subquery here***) c1

    WHERE c1.cum_sum <= c1.OrderQty

    GROUP BY ***c1 fields***) d1

    WHERE d1.GIQty >= d1.OrderQty;
```

The WHERE clause limits the data that gets summed up, but it will only include the next number if it doesnt put the cum_sum over the OrderQty. Im not sure how to change this to include the next record even if it does go above the OrderQty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
with d as (
-- Test Data
SELECT 'j55789' order_Number, 'ks568' part_Number,  8 order_qty, to_date('10-OCT-2015') last_usage_date, 2 usage FROM DUAL union all 
SELECT 'j55789' order_Number, 'ks568' part_Number,  8 order_qty, to_date('11-OCT-2015') last_usage_date, 2 usage FROM DUAL union all 
SELECT 'j55789' order_Number, 'ks568' part_Number,  8 order_qty, to_date('11-OCT-2015') last_usage_date, 2 usage FROM DUAL union all 
SELECT 'j55789' order_Number, 'ks568' part_Number,  8 order_qty, to_date('12-OCT-2015') last_usage_date, 3 usage FROM DUAL union all 
SELECT 'j55789' order_Number, 'ks568' part_Number,  8 order_qty, to_date('13-OCT-2015') last_usage_date, 2 usage FROM DUAL ),
-- Step 1: Get the running sum for each record 
step1 as ( SELECT d.*, sum(usage) over ( partition by order_number, part_number order by last_usage_date) running_sum FROM d ),
-- Step 2: Filter our records that started out beyond our order_qty
step2 as ( SELECT step1.*, row_Number() over ( partition by order_number, part_number order by running_sum desc ) rn from step1 WHERE running_sum - usage < order_qty )
-- Report on the last unfiltered record in the group 
select order_Number, part_number, order_qty, last_usage_date, running_sum usage from step2 where rn = 1
```

Comment: I think this may work. I need to implement it into my code quick and I will update if I have anymore questions.

Comment: Actually I do have a question. Is there a way to modify this so it also shows the usage column if it is null. There are some parts which have no usage at all yet, this only shows rows that have some kind of usage.